# What is the standard for assigning rDNS to unused hosts?

Tags: standards, reverse-dns, rdns

In a range with unused hosts, is the standard to set the rDNS to a generic default one within the network (such as the IP address dot the company's domain name) or is rDNS not meant to be set for an unused host until manually done otherwise as soon as an IP address is used?

Additionally, is there an RFC which supports any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-assigning reverse DNS to IP's is an acceptable practice.  Its use is strongly hinted at in [RFC2317](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt) with the words "**For each size-256 chunk split up using this method, there is a need
   to install close to 256 CNAME records in the parent zone**.  Some
   people might view this as ugly; we will not argue that particular
   point.  It is however quite easy to **automatically generate the CNAME
   resource records in the parent zone once and for all**, if the way the
   address space is partitioned is known."

Comment: Does this go for IPv6 as well? I see a lot of organizations setting a default rDNS for their IPv4 subnets but they leave their IPv6 rDNS's empty until set manually.

Comment: I don't know for sure. I imagine there is no rule against it, but conversely I wonder if IPv6 space is to large to map out prior to it being used.